# Label and data sizing with MP Android

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I can't find an example on setting labels/data with a bigger font.

Doest it exist a simple way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
Typeface mTf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "OpenSans-Bold.ttf");

XAxis xl = chart.getXAxis();
xl.setTypeface(mTf);
xl.setTextSize(6);
```

This set the font for x-axis and adjusts the font size as well. Is this what you are looking for?